# openfire build install4j jar file

Tags: xmpp, openfire, install4j

I am trying to build openfire from the source code. getting compile time error. below classes not found.

```
import com.install4j.api.Context;
import com.install4j.api.ProgressInterface;
import com.install4j.api.UninstallAction;
```

from where we can download these jar files. tried

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.install4j?sort=newest

all the jar file still does not work. Any idea.

Thanks
Mohsin

Answer (score 0):

The install4j artifacts are available from the repository

```
https://maven.ej-technologies.com/repository
```

See https://www.ej-technologies.com/resources/install4j/help/api for more information.

Comment: I added all those jar file, still those above class giving error, I dont know which jar file contains those clases.

Comment: i4jruntime.jar, contained in the dependency `com.install4j:install4j-runtime:7.0.6`

Comment: Ok Got it, I think I am using a latest instal4j jar, the package structure got changed. I need to find out which version of the jar file is required for open fire.

Comment: import com.install4j.api.Context;
import com.install4j.api.ProgressInterface;
import com.install4j.api.UninstallAction;